# How to check more than one value from dictionary in an if statement?

Tags: c#, dictionary, unity-game-engine

Im just starting to learn unity and saw this task in one of my c# studying books. I have to create a code using an if statement inside foreach, so that it checks if i can afford each item in the dictionary, but i have no idea how to check all of them or even once specific, so i could write if 3 times for example.

At the moment my Log shows all the items and thier values, but shows if i can afford only the first one. What should i put in the IF brackets to check every value after it appears it Log?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class LearningCurve : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int currentGold = 3;
    void Start()
    {
        Dictionary<string, int> itemInventory = new Dictionary<string, int>()
        {
            {"Potions", 4 },
            {"Daggers", 3 },
            {"Lockpicks", 1 }
        };

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> itemCost in itemInventory)
        {
            Debug.LogFormat("Item {0} - {1}g", itemCost.Key, itemCost.Value);

            if (currentGold >= itemCost.Value)
            {
                Debug.Log("I can afford that!");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm really confused because what you're asking for ("i have no idea how to check all of them ... What should i put in the IF brackets to check every value after it appears it Log?") is already what you have posted. The foreach goes through each pairing in the Dictionary. `itemCost.Key` is the item's name, and `itemCost.Value` is the gold cost. Your `if` statement already checks your current gold against the item's cost and displays an additional log line if you can afford it.

Comment: Your current code checks if you can afford each individual item in `itemInventory`.  Do you mean that you want to test if you have the `8` gold required to buy _all_ of the items in `itemInventory`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if I understood the question but I will try to give you a basic overview of what is happening in the code you posted.
Let's start with the if, how an if block works is simple you put a boolean bool for short in C# that can have two different values true and a false, inside the if(BOOL VALUE) and if the value is true it will run the code between the { CODE TO RUN }.
Let's refactor the code a bit to see what is going on here.

```
Dictionary<string, int> itemInventory = new Dictionary<string, int>()
    {
        {"Potions", 4 },
        {"Daggers", 3 },
        {"Lockpicks", 1 }
    };

    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> itemCost in itemInventory)
    {
        
        Debug.LogFormat("Item {0} - {1}g", itemCost.Key, itemCost.Value);
        bool iCanBuyitem = currentGold >= itemCost.Value;
        Debug.LogFormat("{0} >= {1} is {2}", currentGold, itemCost.Value,iCanBuyitem);
        if (iCanBuyitem)
        {
             Debug.LogFormat("I can buy {0} ", itemCost.Key);
        }else
        {
             Debug.LogFormat("I can't buy {0} ", itemCost.Key);
        }
    }
```

Unlike in mathematics in programing symbol >= is not an equality symbol but something called a binary operator that takes two variables of one of the many numeric types in c# in your dictionary they are integers Dictionary<string, int> and produce a bool value that tells you if one number is more or equal to a second number, it's a method that has something similar to the the following signature `public bool FirstIsBiggerOrEqualToSecond(int first, int second)`
Here is a dotnet fiddle demonstrating the output https://dotnetfiddle.net/oWlYlY

Comment: Yes, that's it, thank you so much! I used your bool and if/else examples and It worked just as i wanted it to, sorry I described my problem so poorly. I understand most of the points you said, but I don't get why your code inside IF statement applies to all 3 positions in the dictionary, but not just the first one, like my code did.
Is it the bool statement or the "else", what makes that difference and checks if statement after each pair of the dictionary shows in log?

Comment: @Gargatyk Don't worry about the question it's important you want to learn, I would recommend before jumping into unity doing some basic c# tutorials just to understand the basics of programming https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/csharp

Answer (score 0):

Read the question header You mean, if you want to put two or more conditions inside the IF, you have to use `&&` [operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators):

```
if (currentGold >= itemCost.Value && currentGold <= 15)
{
    Debug.Log("I have enough gold to buy this item and it's cheap.");
}
```